# PySimpleGUI drop down menu that changes buttons and options

Tags: drop-down-menu, pysimplegui

I'm new to creating GUI's and my python skills are pretty novice. Is there a way to have a dropdown menu that changes the options/buttons/etc based on which dropdown option I chose. I have a series of tests that I to create a GUI for. Each test has its own options and functions. Instead of having multiple GUI's, I want to make one GUI with a dropdown menu that can let you switch between the different tests.

I tried to google it but perhaps I am not wording it correctly so I cant find any similar codes.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1:Use the Menu() element which add the menu bar at the top of the window and have multiple layers.  You can have them select the top tier and according to which item they select it will show a 2nd tier of choices and even a third tier if wanted.

2:Use the Combo() element where you give a list of choices the user can select.  When you need to change the values you can do an update command to change the values.

Here is sample code that does both options:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
choices = {
            '-SubA-':['Choice A-1','Choice A-2','Choice A-3','Choice A-4','Choice A-5','Choice A-6','Choice A-7'],
            '-SubB-':['Choice B-1','Choice B-2','Choice B-3','Choice B-4','Choice B-5','Choice B-6','Choice B-7'],
            '-SubC-':['Choice C-1','Choice C-2','Choice C-3','Choice C-4','Choice C-5','Choice C-6','Choice C-7'],
            '-SubD-':['Choice D-1','Choice D-2','Choice D-3','Choice D-4','Choice D-5','Choice D-6','Choice D-7'],
          }

menuLayout = [
              ['&Options',[
                 'Group-&A',['Choice A-&1','Choice A-&2','Choice A-&3','Choice A-&4','Choice A-&5','Choice A-&6','Choice A-&7'],
                 'Group-&B',['Choice B-&1','Choice B-&2','Choice B-&3','Choice B-&4','Choice B-&5','Choice B-&6','Choice B-&7'],
                 'Group-&C',['Choice C-&1','Choice C-&2','Choice C-&3','Choice C-&4','Choice C-&5','Choice C-&6','Choice C-&7'],
                 'Group-&D',['Choice D-&1','Choice D-&2','Choice D-&3','Choice D-&4','Choice D-&5','Choice D-&6','Choice D-&7']
              ]]]
layout = [[sg.Menu(menuLayout)],
          [sg.Push(),sg.Combo(choices['-SubA-'],enable_events=True,key='-Choices-'),sg.Push()],
          [sg.R("Group-A","-SubMenuGroup-",key='-SubA-',default=True, enable_events=True),
           sg.R("Group-B","-SubMenuGroup-",key='-SubB-',enable_events=True),
           sg.R("Group-C","-SubMenuGroup-",key='-SubC-',enable_events=True),
           sg.R("Group-D","-SubMenuGroup-",key='-SubD-',enable_events=True)],
          [sg.Push(),sg.Exit(key="-Exit-"),sg.Push()],
          ]
window = sg.Window("Change of Menu options", layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event,values)
    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED,"-Exit-"):
        break
    if (type(event) == str) and event.startswith("-Sub"):
        window['-Choices-'].update(values=choices[event])

window.close()
```